# Difference between a Javascript closure vs generator?

Tags: javascript, closures, generator

I see Javascript closures as functions with local states, which appears to be the same thing as generators.

1. What's the difference between a closure and a generator?
2. What would make one a more fitting tool than another for some context?

Comment: They do completely different things.

Comment: What can a closure do that a generator cannot? They both take an input, do something with respect to an internal state, and execute / return a response, or am I mistaken?

Comment: A closure can contain multiple functions that can be called arbitrarily with arbitrary parameters.  A generator can only be resumed sequentially until it terminates

Comment: Yes, apart from the minor difference that a closure only can be called but a generator object has three different methods that can be invoked on it, they are similar in concept. But have a look at their definitions - replicating the behaviour of a non-trivial generator function is almost impossible with a closure-generating function (by hand).